# Print to HP printer using command line in Linux

Tags: linux, printer, network-printer

I am trying to print text to a networked HP m605dn via IP using the standard lpr unix tool. The system has CUPS and hplip packages installed and running.

I have tried three different URIs and none of them worked:

```
sudo lpadmin -p my-printer -E -v hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_M605?ip=10.1.10.97 -m lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_m604_m605_m606-ps.ppd.gz
sudo lpadmin -p my-printer -E -v ipp://10.1.10.97/ipp/print -m lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_m604_m605_m606-ps.ppd.gz
sudo lpadmin -p my-printer -E -v socket://10.1.10.97:9100 -m lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_m604_m605_m606-ps.ppd.gz
```

In both cases the printer pauses a long time, then spits out a blank page. To test it I am using a command like:

```
lpr my-code.c
```

Where the parameter is a text file. The printer has been set as the default using lpadmin. I have read that HP printers don't accept text file input, but I thought if I am using CUPS it should be sending to the printer correctly, especially if I am using ipp because CUPS "natively" supports ipp.

How do I make progress?

Note that I tried printing a PDF file and it worked, although the margins were incorrect, so I think it is something about the format of the file that is the problem or filtering maybe.

Comment: As the printer supports PCL5, it "understands" plain text and lpr should work fine. Try this command: "cat my-code.c | netcat printer_ip 9100".